# Converting between oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ and standard JDBC classes for DbUnit

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, jdbc, dbunit

I'm running Oracle 10g and have columns with Type_Name

```
TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

When inflated into java classes they come out as

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ
```

But DbUnit can't handle converting Oracle specific classes to Strings for writing to XML. I'm wondering if there's any easy way for me to convert (say, in my SELECT statement somehow) from these Oracle specific timestamps to something in java.sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had to deal with this problem exactly, but I presume that having it come through as a string from the SELECT query would be fine.

You could use the [to_char](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm) function. To convert it to a string. e.g:

```
SQL> select to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD') as d from dual;

D
----------------------------------
2008-10-21 17:00:43.501591
```

This would then be seen by your program as a string. `TZD` includes timezone information (of which there is none in this example)

Later, this could then be parsed by Java using the [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Alternatively, the [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html) class has a method called `dateValue` that returns a `java.sql.Date` class.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to remark that using IYYY as format for the year might not be a good idea unless you really want to get the ISO year. You should use YYYY instead of IYYY.

Try to run your SQL for 31.12.2012 using

```
select to_char(timestamp'2012-12-31 00:00:00 +00:00', 'IYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD') as d from dual;
```

returns "2013-12-31 00:00:00.000000000" which is not the year you would expect.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should probably have been an edit or a comment on the accepted answer but has now been superceded by [dfa's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/223501/revisions)