# Extracting time zone from Oracle JDBC TIMEZONETZ object

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, jdbc, timezone

Is there a way to extract timezone information directly from an `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` object (selected from a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column)?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pull the time zone information directly out of the object without jumping through potentially expensive or fragile hoops (like converting things into strings and parsing those).

You would think that there is an easy way to do this, but I have yet to find one. Oracle's documentation is not very helpful. It claims the last two bytes returned by `TIMESTAMPTZ#toBytes()` encode the timezone information, but there is no description of our to actually decode this information.

Anyone out there have any experience dealing with this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has specific date format elements for these: TZD, TZH, TZM and TZR.

An example:

```
SQL> create table t (col timestamp with time zone)
  2  /

Tabel is aangemaakt.

SQL> insert into t values (sysdate)
  2  /

1 rij is aangemaakt.

SQL> select col
  2       , to_char(col,'TZD') time_zone_daylight_info
  3       , to_char(col,'TZH') time_zone_hour
  4       , to_char(col,'TZM') time_zone_minute
  5       , to_char(col,'TZR') time_zone_region
  6    from t
  7  /

COL                             TIME_Z TIM TI TIME_ZONE_REGION
------------------------------- ------ --- -- --------------------------------
22-05-09 09:12:33,000000 +02:00        +02 00 +02:00    

1 rij is geselecteerd.
```

Or using the EXTRACT function:

```
SQL> select col
  2       , extract(timezone_abbr from col)   time_zone_abbr
  3       , extract(timezone_hour from col)   time_zone_hour
  4       , extract(timezone_minute from col) time_zone_minute
  5       , extract(timezone_region from col) time_zone_region
  6    from t
  7  /

COL                             TIME_ZONE_                         TIME_ZONE_HOUR                       TIME_ZONE_MINUTE
------------------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
TIME_ZONE_REGION
----------------------------------------------------------------
22-05-09 09:15:24,000000 +02:00 UNK                                             2                                      0
UNKNOWN


1 rij is geselecteerd.
```

Comment: Thanks.

I don't suppose there is a way to do this without using format elements or the extract function (i.e., I have an existing application I'd like to make timezone-aware, and it would be nice if I could do this without changing all the existing SQL statements)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This post seems to suggest the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223096?sort=oldest. You can of course apply the Chinese method: setting to all possible time zone information and watch the last two bytes ...

Answer (score 0):

The format of TIMESTAMPTZ is [well documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html). We currently use [the following code](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa/blob/master/threeten-jpa-oracle-impl/src/main/java/com/github/marschall/threeten/jpa/oracle/impl/TimestamptzConverter.java) to extract the time zone information.

If you are on Java SE 8 you can use `getObject(int, OffsetDateTime.class)`, if you use `getObject(int, ZonedDateTime.class)` you may be affected by [bug 25792016](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=25792016).