# Why rsmd.getColumnClassName(index) showing strange results

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to pull data from Oracle EMP Table through Java( Added one extra column to original table with Data type as TIMESTAMPTZ) .
While I try to find the Data types through java using below methods, it shows different RESULTS than what I am expecting.

```
System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(index)+"-->"+rsmd.getColumnType(index)+"-->"+rsmd.getColumnClassName(index)+"  ");
```

Here is the output

```
EMPNO-->2-->java.math.BigDecimal  
ENAME-->12-->java.lang.String  
JOB-->12-->java.lang.String  
MGR-->2-->java.math.BigDecimal  
HIREDATE-->93-->java.sql.Timestamp  
SAL-->2-->java.math.BigDecimal  
COMM-->2-->java.math.BigDecimal  
DEPTNO-->2-->java.math.BigDecimal  
TSTMP-->-101-->oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ
```

1) "2" corresponds to Numeric in java.sql.Types.
Here it displayed for NUMBER and NUMBER(7,2) columns in EMP table, why is the class showing java.math.BigDecimal which I believe is for decimals (NUMBER(7,2) in this case).

2) Also I donot see TIMESTAMPTZ in java Types. It is being taken care by Oracle JDBC. Doesn't java supports all oracle DataTypes?

I am writing this data to another table. So Finally I have decided to use Object in my code leaving everything to java for conversion.

```
if(obj instanceof java.math.BigDecimal)
     tgtSt.setObject(index, obj);
else if(obj instanceof java.lang.String)
    tgtSt.setObject(index, obj);
else if(obj instanceof java.sql.Timestamp)
   tgtSt.setObject(index, obj);
else if(obj instanceof oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ)
  tgtSt.setObject(index, obj);
```

3) Would there be any problem with this approach of using Objects?
4) Also when getObject() and setObject() methods gets the work done why do we have other methods like getInt() getString().....
Please help me with these questions.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223096/converting-between-oracle-sql-timestamptz-and-standard-jdbc-classes-for-dbunit

Comment: Thanks user.But it doesnt answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the class showing java.math.BigDecimal

Examine [The JDBC API Specification 4.2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html)

TABLE B-3 on page 192 shows *Standard Mapping from JDBC Types to Java types*, there is, among others:

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| JDBC Type        |        Java Type      |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| NUMERIC          |  java.math.BigDecimal |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

That is, all numeric types are mapped by defautl to `java.math.BigDecimal` class

---

> Also I donot see TIMESTAMPTZ in java Types

`TIMESTAMPTZ` type (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) is not defined in SQL standard, it is proprietrary Oracle's type, you cannot find it in the JDBC specification.
Please consult [Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/title.htm) 
Table [A-1 Valid SQL Data Type-Java Class Mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28906) shows all allowed data mappings implemented by the driver, you can see there that `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is maped to `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` class which is not available in `java.sql` package, but it is internal class packaged in the  driver jar.

---

> 3) Would there be any problem with this approach of using Objects?

As usual the answer is **It depends**. You can do it this way, but it will be tedious and error-prone, I do not know what the reason is to do it this way, this is like reinventing the wheel.
 There are plenty of tools and frameworks which provide JDBC/Java type mapping and conversion out of the box, beginning from basic [PreparedStatement and ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), throuht [Spring's JDBCTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-core), up to JPA/Orm frameworks like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) or [Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#jpa) or [MyIbatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/)

Comment: Thanks krokodilko. You explanation helps me.Thanks much